# Next.js CLI - is it possible to pre-build certain routes when running dev locally?

Tags: build, next.js

I'm part of an org with an enterprise app built on Next.js, and as it's grown the local dev experience has been degrading.  The main issue is that our pages make several calls to `/api` routes on load, and those are built lazily when you run `yarn dev`, so you're always forced to sit and wait in the browser while that happens.

I've been thinking it might be better if we were able to actually pre-build all of the `/api` routes right away when `yarn dev` is run, so we'd get a better experience when the browser is opened.  I've looked at the [CLI docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development) but it seems the only options for `dev` are `-p` (port) and `-H` (host).  I also don't think running `yarn build` first will work as I assume the build output is quite different between the build and dev commands.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: A hack can be to write a shell script to list all files inside `pages/api` and replace the entities like `[param]` with some dummy value (say 0), doesn't actually matter as long as your handler is properly validating the input. Then invoke a GET request using cURL for each endpoint. The method of request also doesn't matter as the handlers in Next.js check the method after the files are compiled. After writing (& testing), run this script in another terminal session after the (dev) server has started. It will take some time, but after that it should take relatively less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to prebuild them, but you can tell Next how long to keep them before discarding and rebuilding. Check out the [onDemandEntries](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/configuring-onDemandEntries) docs. We had a similar issue and solved it for a big project about a year ago with this in our `next.config.js`:

```js
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require("next/constants")

module.exports = (phase, {}) => {
  let devOnDemandEntries = {}
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
    devOnDemandEntries = {
      // period (in ms) where the server will keep pages in the buffer
      maxInactiveAge: 300 * 1000,
      // number of pages that should be kept simultaneously without being disposed
      pagesBufferLength: 5,
    }
  }
  return {
    onDemandEntries,
    ...
  }
}
```